# Data augmentation for Deep learning

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on grass weed detection using CNN. I have 2 classes at the moment and for each class, I have 18 images. Can I apply data augmentation method to increase the dataset to use CNN? and how much data would be sufficient?

Also, which methods I can compare with the CNN to show the better performance of CNN than other methods?

Comment: I think you should to go with other methods, rather than trying CNN with such small dataset, you will only fell into over-fitting your data and nothing else with low validation accuracy. I would suggest you to try out the haar and cascade method for this, where you can extract features and feed into a classifier. Haar and cascades is reliable method with decent amount of accuracy.Hope this helps!

Comment: Better if you upload some of those images. Anyway, you will have keep in mind about the variations your image have like luminance or others.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you plan to have 5.000 images by class (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/), if you want to use straight up deep learning. You can decrease this number by using fine tuning (medium number of samples ~1000) or transfer learning (low number samples ~100). Those are numbers before using augmentation.

Sure you can use augmentations to increase the effective size of your dataset, but that is not the same as having at least 100 images. Deep Learning is very data intensive and therefore is not a good fit to 18 images.

Other methods are mostly handcrafted. You can do something like a hog features and use any kind of other ML technique as classification like SVM/Boosting/Bagging/etc.

Comment: Ok regarding the dataset what i have understood is to have atleast 100-200 images then apply data augmentation. But in his earlier comment he mentioned that with hog is performing betting when comparing to CNN.. is it possible?

Comment: If you have only 18 images hog and svms will probably get better performance. I did use hog features with neural networks before and I got ~ 45% accuracy instead of the 90+ with current deep learning models on 40.000 training examples for 10 classes. Now if i had only used 100 or so training examples the accuracy might only have been 30% or so.

Comment: No it has been applied on augmented data of 14000 images in each class..

Comment: I can not prove that a CNN is better than traditional approaches, which is why I used an example of my own experiment, where I tried to compare them to each other and there CNN worked way better.

Comment: Is it correct that HoG and Svm works better with small amount (less diverse) data?

Answer (score 0):

- With just 18 images CNN will work good but won't achieve outstanding results
- With 18 images there are chances of CNN to overfit the training data so which CNN model you would use might be tricky
- I would suggest to use HOG+SVM for this problem and they will perform very well
- But If you do use Data Augmentation then yes your CNN will perform outstanding results
- you can use [keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) that will generate data for you. You have to just specify how many images do you want to generate
- You can also flip the 18 images and rotate the images and translating the images to augment data by yourself
- For more sophisticated Image Augmentation you can refer this **[link](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)**